# Finding rate of change with integration (my solution correct?)

Tags: calculus, integration

The rate of change in a person's body temperature, with respect to the dosage of $x$ milligrams of a drug, is given by $D'(x)=\frac{7}{x+8}$. One milligram raises the temperature 3.7 C. Find the function giving the total change.

My solution
\begin{align}
D(x) &= 7 \ln|x + 8|+C\\
D(1) &= 7 \ln|9|+C = 3.7\\
C &= 3.7 - 7 \ln 9
\end{align}

So we have

\begin{align}
D(x) &= 7 \ln |x + 8| + (3.7 - 7 \ln 9)\\
&= 7 \ln{\frac{|x + 8|}{9}} + 3.7 
\end{align}
Is this correct? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your work looks good, nice write up.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. I would've removed the absolute value sign since the dosage is always non-negative. In a "real world" problem, remember that the physical/biological interpretation always trumps the pure mathematical solution.